# for loop when reading lines from a list

Tags: python, extract

I have a list which has used regular express to extract, the list will be like the following:

```
                     SRM Video Dest            UDP   QAM      QAM    PID   In     Out    Detected Input Output PSI      Uptime
Session ID           ID  Intf  IpAddress       Port  Chan     Domain Remap ProgNo ProgNo Bitrate  State State  Detected (s)    Encryption
-------------------- --- ----- --------------- ----- -------- ------ ----- ------ ------ -------- ----- ------ -------- ------ ----------
000a000905000176794c 1   1     232.232.40.1    55000 0/0/48   2      No    62351  62351  46000    Off    On     Yes      3175405 Clear     
000a000905000176794d 1   1     232.232.40.1    55000 0/0/49   2      No    62351  62351  46000    On    On     Yes      3175405 Clear     
000a000905000176794e 1   1     232.232.40.1    55000 0/0/50   2      No    62351  62351  46000    Off    Off     Yes      3175405 Clear
```

The reading logic is as belows where w00 and w0 are two commands line. I extracted the content between two commands.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as fp_nei:
            fp_reader = fp_nei.read()
            pat = re.compile(w00 + '(.*?)' + w0, re.S)
            videosession = pat.findall(fp_reader)
```

I want to filter the line when "Detected Bitrate" is zero or "Input State" is "Off".

Like the following:

```
                     SRM Video Dest            UDP   QAM      QAM    PID   In     Out    Detected Input Output PSI      Uptime
Session ID           ID  Intf  IpAddress       Port  Chan     Domain Remap ProgNo ProgNo Bitrate  State State  Detected (s)    Encryption
-------------------- --- ----- --------------- ----- -------- ------ ----- ------ ------ -------- ----- ------ -------- ------ ----------
000a000905000176794c 1   1     232.232.40.1    55000 0/0/48   2      No    62351  62351  46000    Off    On     Yes      3175405 Clear        
000a000905000176794e 1   1     232.232.40.1    55000 0/0/50   2      No    62351  62351  46000    Off    Off     Yes      3175405 Clear
```

I tried to useee a simple way like the following, but it seems that the output show all the lines instead of lines with "Off".

```
for line in videosession:
    if "Off" in line:
        print(line)
```

Would you please shed some lights on it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you paste your data in more copy-paste format ?

Comment: Why don't you use a data frame instead? That would be easier.

Comment: @user2906838, I don't want to use pandas as the code will be package as an exe and pandas module will take a large size. Could we do that without using pandas?

Comment: isn't it that, your input is full text, not the list? you have noted list in the question and that is confusing. You could actually start from the beginning, by providing a sample of your file content, and how did you get the list from that. What does w0 and w00 represents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the line and compare the columns. The lines looks like space separated. So once you split it, column index is fixed. Example Detected Bitrate is 10 and Input State is 11.

```
with open('testfile_data', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as fp_nei:
            lines = fp_nei.readlines()
            i = 0
            for line in lines:
                value = line.strip().replace('-', '').strip() 
                if len(value) == 0:
                    break
                i += 1
            lines = lines[i+1:]

for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split()
    if split_line[11] == 'Off' or float(split_line[10]) == 0.0:
        print(line)
```

Note: File reading and removing the headers is not efficient. If the headers is constant then just do lines = lines[3:] to obtain the rows directly rather than the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. However, it printed an error  "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Input'". If I just print (split_line[1]), it will just print "Video". Is that because of the space between the strings?

Comment: Could you put your lines reading logic. The code I guess assumes that lines has value only rows and not the row heading. But it looks like column/row headers are not removed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my questions. Hope it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must cut the text by `splitlines`:

```
for line in videosessions.splitlines():
```

Then split each line at spaces:

```
parts = line.split()
```

and check

```
parts[10]==0 and parts[11]=="Off"
```

You must omit empty lines and lines starting with "---" or "Session".

Comment: It seems that AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. Why do we need to use splitlines under this circumstances?

Comment: @Winnie-c You don't need it if you really have a list (as you said) but you presented a text,i.e. a long string. That was my start point.

Comment: It is a list. It shows as a list if you print(type(videosession)). I don'e understand if we print(parts[10]) it will only display "input".

Comment: if it's a list, then why not you show as a list in the question. There is the plain text in the question. That makes it hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out. Thanks for everyone's help. 
Actually it is a list which contains list. You need to extract each line from the list and combine them to be a new list. 
That is why my code at the beginning did not work.

Here is the code.

```
num=[]
split_line=[]
row = []
for line in videosession:
    split_line=line.split()
for i,v in enumerate(split_line):
    if v=="Clear" :
        num.append(i)
for k,val in enumerate(num):
    start=0 + k * 16
    end=val+1
    row.append(split_line[start:end])

for m,n in enumerate(row):
    if "Off" in row[m] or float(row[m][10])==0.0:
        print(row[m])
```